# jQuery combine select function for several select boxes

Tags: jquery

I have a page with many different items and I want the items to be "filterable". The items are categorized by "Speaker" "Subject" and "Language". I have an HTML select box for each category.

I created 3 separate jQuery functions which filter the page content based on the select boxes. This works. But they only work separately. When I select a language it filters correctly, then when I select a specific subject, it ignores the language-setting and filters only the subject.

How do I make all three functions work together so that I can select a speaker and a language and a subject or any one/two/three?

This is the code I have sofar:

```
handleNewSelection = function () {
    switch ($(this).val()) {
        case 'english':
            $(".ENG").show();
        break;
        case 'french':
            $(".FRE").show();
        break;
        case 'german':
            $(".GER").show();
    }
};

handleNewSpeaker = function () {
    switch ($(this).val()) {
        case 'all':
            $(".Speaker1").show();
            $(".Speaker2").show();
            $(".Speaker3").show();
        break;
        case 'speaker1':
            $(".Speaker1").show();
            $(".Speaker2").hide();
            $(".Speaker3").hide();
        break;
        case 'speaker2':
            $(".Speaker1").hide();
            $(".Speaker2").show();
            $(".Speaker3").hide();
        break;
        case 'speaker3':
            $(".Speaker1").hide();
            $(".Speaker2").hide();
            $(".Speaker3").show();
    }
};

handleNewSubject = function () {
    switch ($(this).val()) {
        case 'all':
            $(".Subject1").show();
            $(".Subject1").show();
            $(".Subject1").show();   
        break;
        case 'subject1':
            $(".Subject1").show();
            $(".Subject2").hide();
            $(".Subject3").hide();
        break;
         case 'subject2':
            $(".Subject1").hide();
            $(".Subject2").show();
            $(".Subject3").hide();
        break;
         case 'subject3':
            $(".Subject1").hide();
            $(".Subject2").hide();
            $(".Subject3").show();
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Run the event handlers once now to ensure everything is as it should be
    $("#language_selector").change(handleNewSelection);
    handleNewSelection.apply($("#language_selector"));
    
    $("#speaker_selector").change(handleNewSpeaker);
    handleNewSpeakers.apply($("#speaker_selector"));
    
    $("#subject_selector").change(handleNewSubject);
    handleNewSpeakers.apply($("#subject_selector"));
});


let language = (new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)).get('language') ?? 'english';
    $('#language_selector').val(language);
    handleNewSelection();
   
let speaker = (new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)).get('speaker') ?? 'all';
    $('#speaker_selector').val(speaker);
    handleNewSpeaker();
    
let subject = (new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)).get('subject') ?? 'all';
    $('#subject_selector').val(subject);
    handleNewSubject();
```

Comment: Make one `change` handler that always checks all `<select>` elements and then sets the visibility of the dependent elements.

Comment: You could just move all the switch statements into a single function, and manually grab the three elements values by their IDs at the start of that function (Assuming you only want those 3 elements specifically)

Comment: Store the result of `new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)` in a variable so you don't have to create a new `URLSearchParams` object for every parameter you want to do something with.